# How to reload UIImage loaded asynchronously with SDWebImage in UITableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sdwebimage

The problem is that I don't know how to refresh images loaded asynchronously from url with SDWebImage.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    let item = items[indexPath.row]
    
    if let url = URL(string: item.stringUrl) {
        let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "noPhoto.png")
        itemImage.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
    }

    cell.imageView?.image = itemImage.image
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "item id: \(item.id)"
    return cell
}
```

The images will only refresh after scrolling through the table. Until then the table only shows placeHolder image which is expected as it only reloads images when cells are reused. I tried to use the completion handler to refresh images when loaded using tableview.reload() as shown below:

```
   itemImage.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: placeholderImage, completed: {image,error,cache,url in
        if image != nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
```

This solution results in tableView loading all the images in a second which is what I want but it reloads the whole table basically every time I try to scroll through it so it "pushes" the whole table to the top position instantly.

The last solution I tries is this:

```
  itemImage.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: placeholderImage, completed: {image,error,cache,url in
        if image != nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
            }
        }
    })
```

This also doesn't and makes tableview randomly showing and hiding images.

I suppose the problem is that I try to reload images in a function that creates cells but I can't find a solution to how resolve this issue. I will be very grateful for any help.

Comment: On the first code shown, just remove `cell.imageView?.image = itemImage.image`, that should be fine.

Comment: `sd_setImage(with:completion:)` will set the image already before calling the closure.

Comment: In this case where do I assign the image to the cell? Because when I just remove this line the image isn't loaded in cell at all.

Comment: I just read it correctly, it's `cell.imageView?.image = itemImage.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)` `Item` doesn't need to have a `UIImageView` property.

Comment: Yes I just tried it exactly likes this and it worked. Thank you very much!